# Regularly of Neuman and Dirichlet problem

Tags: elliptic-pde, regularity

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n=2,3$ be a bounded domain with $\Gamma$ Lipschitz boundary (regularly) such that $\Gamma=\Gamma_D\cup\Gamma_N$. Assume that $h \in L^2(\Gamma)$ and $a \in C(\bar{\Omega})$ with $a\geq a_0>0$. Let $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ be the weak solution of the following problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
    -\nabla \cdot(a \nabla u)&=0 \quad \text { in } \Omega \\
    u&=0 \quad \text { on }  \Gamma_D \\
(a \nabla u).n&=h \quad \text { on } \Gamma_N.
\end{aligned}
$$
and satisfied $$    \left\|u\right\|_{W^{1,2}} \leq c \left\|h\right\|_{L^{2}(\Gamma)}\hbox{,}$$

**Question: For which conditions on the space of $h$ and $\Omega$, for the solution of this problem must satisfy the following regularity: $u\in W^{1,4}(\Omega)$ or $\nabla u\in L^4(\Omega)$?**